# Select all the existing sheets from a workbook using pywin32 / How to transform a string input to a list

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32, win32com

LE: Any method to select all the existing sheets from a workbook using pywin32?

I am opening an Excel workbook using win32com.client.

I want the user to be able to select a number of sheets.

How can I transform the user's input into a list?

I tried:

```
USER_INP = simpledialog.askstring(title="Sheets to be converted",
                                  prompt="How many sheets do you need?")


print(USER_INP)
z = str(USER_INP)




ws_index_list = []

if z == 1:
    ws_index_list = [1]
elif z == 2:
    ws_index_list = [1,2]
elif z == 3:
    ws_index_list = [1,2,3]
elif z == 4:
    ws_index_list = [1,2,3,4]
elif z == 5:
    ws_index_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
elif z == 6:
    ws_index_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
elif z == 7:
    ws_index_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
elif z == 8:
    ws_index_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
elif z == 9:
    ws_index_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
elif z == 10:
    ws_index_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

But it does not work. It works if I give it a predefined list such as:

```
ws_index_list = [1,2]
```

Error:

```
 line 75, in <module>
    wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 186, in __call__
    return self._get_good_object_(self._oleobj_.Invoke(*allArgs),self._olerepr_.defaultDispatchName,None)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352571), 1)
```

Also, why if I want to export my file as "final test 2" it gets the name "final%test%2". How can I replace the "%?"

PS: I know that my code is a mess, that's why I am asking for help :) hopefully I won't get any downvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
USER_INP = simpledialog.askstring(title="Sheets to be converted",
                                  prompt="How many sheets do you need?")


z = str(USER_INP)



ws_index_list = []

if z == str(1):
    ws_index_list.extend([1])
elif z == str(2):
    ws_index_list.extend([1,2])
elif z == str(3):
    ws_index_list.extend([1,2,3])
elif z == str(4):
    ws_index_list.extend([1,2,3,4])
elif z == str(5):
    ws_index_list.extend([1,2,3,4,5])
elif z == str(6):
    ws_index_list.extend([1,2,3,4,5,6])
elif z == str(7):
    ws_index_list.extend([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
elif z == str(8):
    ws_index_list.extend([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
elif z == str(9):
    ws_index_list.extend([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
elif z == str(10):
    ws_index_list.extend([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```